# How do i filter the array in object of array?

Tags: reactjs

How do i filter `roles` in this array to return true when `"Admin"` is found?

```
const array = [{
    "country": "all",
    "roles": [
        "Normal",
        "Admin",
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.Did u mean to return a boolean overall?

In **Js es6**, you could use `.some()`  [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

it's nice and simple :)

```js
const array = [{
    "country": "all",
    "roles": [
        "Normal",
        "Admin",
    ]
}, {
    "country": "test",
    "roles": [
        "Normal"
    ]
}]

const result = array.some(o => Boolean(o.roles.some(role => role === 'Admin')))

console.log(result) // return true
```

2.Or, did u mean that it returns a `new array` in which each roles become a boolean depending on having 'Admin' or not?

If it is, `.some()` works as well :)

Try below:

```js
const array = [{
    "country": "all",
    "roles": [
        "Normal",
        "Admin",
    ]
}, {
    "country": "test",
    "roles": [
        "Normal"
    ]
}]

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    const item = Object.assign({}, curr, { roles: curr.roles.some(o => o === 'Admin') })
    acc.push(item)
    return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)  // return true
```

or if it filter an array, my answer is the same as Tobias' :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.filter()` and `.includes()`:

```
const admins = array.filter((u) => u.roles.includes("Admin"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  const array = [{
   "country": "all",
   "roles": [
    "Normal",
    "Admin",
   ]
   }]

    const val = array.map((a) => a.roles.includes('Admin'))
                  
    console.log(val) //return true
```